# why internet disconnects so often?

Tags: 10.04, internet, modem

I use docomo 2G in a modem to browse. when I am surfing, the internet suddenly disconnects("this may due to the network").

> **but when i try to reconnect, it is not connecting**
>   ***I have to unplug my modem and plug it, or i have to reboot my system*** to reconnect it

version ubuntu 10.04
why this happens??

Comment: Can't you upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10?

Comment: I had a problem with grub for 12.10. i'm running dual os. this version only suits my system

Comment: Have you installed driver from dongle or you are using generic driver in `network-connections` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install two software packages to make the internet connectivity work consistently without breaking. They are wvdial and gnome-ppp (The front-end tool to configure wvdial).

1) Install wvdial package

Open terminal,(alt+ctrl+t) and type the following command

`sudo apt-get install wvdial`

2) Install gnome-ppp

`sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp`

3) Open gnome-ppp from the terminal.

`sudo gnome-ppp`

4)You have to enter your docomo 10-digit mobile number in the Username & your password. Phone= `*99***1#` or if that doesnt work enter phone=`*99#`. Then press the Setup button below.

5) In the Setup window below, click the “Detect” button to identify the device ID of the USB port in which you have inserted your USB modem. The tool would automatically detect the Device, Type and Speed of your USB modem. Once it has deteced, please the “Close” button below.

Once this is done click on Connect!!!

You could also download and install ixconn. You can get it [here](http://www.mwconn.net/download_ixconn.html).